# Struggling with CS50 Readability

Tags: c, cs50

so I'm struggling with why I continue to get undeclared identifiers and can't seem to understand why the code isn't running properly. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to work through this.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        // Count letters
        a = count_letters(text);

        // Count words (between spaces), words = space + 1
        b = count_words(text);

        // Count sentences (# of .?! in text)
        c = count_sentences(text);
    }

    float L = a / (float)b * 100;
    float S = c / (float)b * 100;

    int CLI = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);

    if (CLI < 1) {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    } else if (CLI > 16) {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    } else {
        printf("Grade %i\n", CLI);
    }
}

int count_letters(string text) {
    int letters = 0;

    if (text[i] > 'a' && text[i] < 'z' || text[i] > 'A' && text[i] < 'Z') {
        letters++;
    }
}

int count_words(string text) {
    int word = 1;

    if (text[i] == ' ') {
        words++;
    }
}

int count_sentences(string text) {
    int sentence = 0;

    if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!') {
        sentence++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that usually, If you have to *count* something, you should initialize a variable to zero and add one at any occurrency. Can you follow in your debugger what happens to `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: You probably want to return something from `count_letters`, etc...

Comment: You are trying to access `i` outside of `main` but `i` is local to `main`. In `count_words` you declare `word` but try to increase `words`. Also, you never `return words;` from `count_words`. `count_sentences` doesn't `return sentence;` and `count_letters` does not `return letters;`

Comment: Please don't just say "get undeclared identifiers", but rather, post the error including the list of undeclared identifiers. Then we can help much more easily.

Comment: Sidenote: The title is _"Struggling with CS50 **Readability**"_ - So, name your variables properly. `a` is not a good name for a variable holding the letter count etc.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the symbol MISSING and implemented the functionality of cs50.h you did not share with us.  You can delete all but `#include <cs50.h>` from that first section.

You iterate over your text in `main`, so you only need to operate on a single letter `c` in your count functions (and words is incremented if there were letters but no spaces).   This was your main issue.

Moved `main()` to the end, so you don't need the function declarations for the count functions.  Used better variable names and initialized those variables.  Not sure what `L`, `S`, or `CLI` are.  It would be a good idea to define constants for your magical values (0.0588, 0.296, 15.8).

```
#define MISSING
#ifndef MISSING
#include <cs50.h>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef char * string;
#define MAX_STR 1000
// caller frees returned string
string get_string(const char *prompt) {
    char *s = malloc(MAX_STR);
    if(!s) return NULL;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    fgets(s, MAX_STR, stdin);
    return s;
}
#endif

#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters(char c) {
    return isalpha(c);
}

int count_words(char c) {
    return c == ' ';
}

int count_sentences(char c) {
    return (c == '.') || (c == '?') || (c == '!');
}

int main(void) {
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        letters += count_letters(text[i]);
        words += count_words(text[i]);
        sentences += count_sentences(text[i]);
    }
    if(!words && letters) words++;

    float L = 100.0 * letters / words;
    float S = 100.0 * sentences / words;
    int CLI = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);
    if (CLI < 1) {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    } else if (CLI <= 16) {
        printf("Grade %i\n", CLI);
    } else {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```